# What does a public constructor on an internal class mean

Tags: c#, .net, visibility, internal

I've seen some C# code that declares a class with an `internal` modifier, with a `public` constructor:

```
internal class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```

What is the point of having a public constructor, if the visibility of the entire class is internal, thus it can be seen only inside the defining assembly?

Also, does this make any sense in case *SomeClass* is a nested class?

Comment: If you create an internal UserControl with an internal constructor, the Win Forms designer will misbehave.

Comment: Think of the access modifier on the class as a kind of "master switch" which sets the *maximum* accessibility of all of the class's members.

Comment: @ChrisMcGrath. Largely I would agree, though this question does also ask about nesting of classes (and I missed that on my first read, so I've addressed it in an edit to my answer).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `internal class` scope overrides the `public MyClass()` constructor scope, making the constructor `internal`.

Using `public` on the constructor makes it easier to update the class to `public` later, but confuses intent. I don't do it.

*Edit 3: I missed part of your question. It is still fine to do that if your class is nested. The nesting can't make any difference, even if it is nested in a private class in a public class in a ... (see [C# language specification - 3.5.2 Accessibility domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691128%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).*

**EDIT:** And, if i recall, if the ctor is `internal`, it can't be used as a generic type where there is a constraint requiring `where T : new()`, this would require a `public` constructor (ref. [C# language specification (version 4.0) - 4.4.3 Bound and unbound types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx)).

**Edit 2:** Code sample demonstrating the above

```
class Program
{
    internal class InternalClass {
        internal InternalClass() { }
    }
    internal class InternalClassPublicCtor {
        public InternalClassPublicCtor() { }        
    }
    internal class GenericClass<T>
        where T : new() {}

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        GenericClass<InternalClass> doesNotCompile = new GenericClass<InternalClass>();
        GenericClass<InternalClassPublicCtor> doesCompile = new GenericClass<InternalClassPublicCtor>();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am of the same mind on confusing intent unless you have a lot of constructors it shouldn't be too difficult to change your constructors  to public after an update and many refactoring tools will suggest this as well

Comment: In order for dependency injection and reflection to work you have to mark your constructors public even if your class is internal.

Answer (score 11):

From [MSDN - Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Normally, the accessibility of a member is not greater than the accessibility of the type that contains it. However, a public member of an internal class might be accessible from outside the assembly if the member implements interface methods or overrides virtual methods that are defined in a public base class.

So if, for example, you have an internal implementation of a public interface, you can still expose certain members as public.

Additionally, suppose you suddenly want your internal class to be public. It's a lot easier simply to change the access modifier on the class than all of the members.