# Moving properties down from base class to child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, parent

I've been struggling understanding some of the fundamentals of OOP. 
I'm practicing by creating a chess game where I create a class that initializes all the movement properties of all the pieces.

```
public class Piece  //<T> // using ' T '  as the generic variable of all the below- 
{

    //Movement of all pieces are constructed from this properties of this base class ('Piece')- 
    private int StepsLeft;
    private int StepsRight;
    private int StepsUp;
    private int StepsBack;
    //Diaganols: 
    private int DiagTopL;
    private int DiagTopR;
    private int DiagBotL;
    private int DiagBotR;
    public int StartPositionVert; // Vertical starting value: '1 thru 8'     -
    public string StartPositionHoriz; // Horizontal starting value: ' a thru h' -

    //property 
    public int Left{
        get { return StepsLeft; }
        // Setting it equal to 'T' ?
        set {             
            Left = StepsLeft; }
    }
    public int Right
    {
        get { return StepsRight; }
        // Setting it equal to 'T' ?
        set { Right = StepsRight; }
    }
    public int Up
    {
        get { return StepsUp; }
        // Setting it equal to 'T' ?
        set { Up = StepsUp; }
    }
     public int etc.
```

I created a child class for pawns but I don't seem to understand how constructors work well enough to create a functional one that inherits the properties from the parent..

```
  class Pawn : Piece
{ // class for a single pawn piece

    public Pawn() //   << RED SYNTAX ERROR RIGHT HERE
    {
        bool FirstMove = true;
        Left = 0;
        Right = 0;
        Up = 2;  //< start it at two?-
        Back = 0;
        DTopLeft = 0; //start these off at zero- 
        DTopRight = 0; // - ^ 
        DBotLef = 0;  // < always -0-
        DBotRite = 0; //  < always -0-
    }
    public override void Move()
    {
        base.Move();// <<==- replace
    }
}
```

Visual Studio is showing an error right over the word 'Pawn' (my constructor)

How am I using this wrong? The properties are able to be called and assigned within the constructor but what values should I be including in the ()'s.. ex. Pawn(int value, int value 2, int propertyName, etc)

I've watched a hundred tutorial videos now but I still don't get it. I hope what I'm trying to accomplish even makes sense!!

Hovering over the red line, the actual error message is:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'StepsLeft' of 'Piece.Piece(int, int)'

Comment: Like I don't understand why it needs more arguments. Is there somewhere else within the pawn class that I should be initializing this?

Comment: where is firstMove define? What is the error message?

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Hover over the red line and tell us what the message is that appears in the tooltip.

Comment: Some other thoughts, while awaiting that information... Consider making the `Piece` class abstract, since it is just a base class and you would not expect to create a class of that type, just the derived types. Similarly, the private fields in it could be changed to protected: then the `Pawn` class can directly set the fields from the constructor rather than going through the property setters (which is a [bad idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2214-do-not-call-overridable-methods-in-constructors?view=vs-2017))

Comment: My bet is that `Piece` has a constructor (requiring parameters) that you haven't shown us, so it's complaining that there is no suitable constructor on the base class.

Comment: @CSSSuit - Please read [ask] and then provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: I apologize, guys! thanks for all your responses! the actual error message is:  ' there is no argument given that corresponds to the rquired formal parameter 'StepsLeft' of 'Piece.Piece(int, int) '  I tried passing in the properties (ex. 'Left'/ 'Right' and even the private fields (ex. StepsLeft / StepsRight) into the parentheses but the error persists. I think I have entirely misunderstood the purpose of this.

Comment: @Richardissimo I just tried that but I have the same err :/

Comment: @Richardissimo omg you were right about the ctor. I just added one and included nothing within the body and it started working. I thought that the constructor was implied though with it just being a class?? OOP IS CONFUSING!!!

Comment: Is there any `Constructor' in `Piece` class? and if yes can you write it please. Also I notice another problem in the properties, there is an infinite loop when you are setting there values, you need to replace `{Left = StepsLeft;}` with `{StepsLeft = value;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written in the comment: *My bet is that `Piece` has a constructor (requiring parameters) that you haven't shown us, so it's complaining that there is no suitable constructor on the base class.*

The OP has confirmed this was exactly what the problem was. The `Piece` class has a constructor taking two `int`s. So let me explain...

If you write a class without any constructors, your class is given a default constructor, with no parameters. If you add a constructor, then that default constructor will not be added - if you want it, you need to write it yourself.

The purpose of a constructor is to say what values *must* be given when that class is constructed.

The problem with the code in the question is that the derived class's constructor does not specify which base class constructor to use, and since the base class has no default constructor, the statement is not valid.

You could make the constructor valid like this...

```
public Pawn()
    : base (1, 2)
{
```

Which would use the constructor of the base class, passing values 1 and 2 to the two `int` parameters of the base class constructor (possibly not what you need, but I'm demonstrating your options). Or you could add parameters to your `Piece` constructor, and pass those variable names in:

```
public Pawn(not first, int second)
    : base (first, second)
{
```

from the error message, It looks like those would be called StepsLeft, StepsRight.

Or you could add the default constructor onto the base class (if that is acceptable), in which case there is no need to change the `Pawn` code.

But you cannot pass your properties or fields into the base constructor because your class has not been constructed yet!

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me going, @Richardissimo I have been very slow to pick up with these oop concepts. even though it really does look almost fun once you get the hang of it. Check out my updated code and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, the base class required a "written-out" constructor with and a public access identifier did the job. I have upateded the code to include:

```
    public class Piece  //<T> // using ' T '  as the generic variable of all the below- 
{
    public Piece()
    {


}
```

and the child class is now, no longer complaining. 
I'm going to a coding bootcamp where I can hopefully get more of the fundamentals sorted out! Thank you guys for the input!

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio is throwing an error because you don't have an access modifier on your Pawn class, but you are setting the constructor to public.

If you don't specify an access modifier, the default is internal. Having a class be internal but then trying to have a public constructor is what is causing your issue.

```
public  class Pawn : Piece
{ // class for a single pawn piece

    public Pawn() //   << RED SYNTAX ERROR RIGHT HERE
    {
        bool FirstMove = true;
        Left = 0;
        Right = 0;
        Up = 2;  //< start it at two?-
        Back = 0;
        DTopLeft = 0; //start these off at zero- 
        DTopRight = 0; // - ^ 
        DBotLef = 0;  // < always -0-
        DBotRite = 0; //  < always -0-
    }
    public override void Move()
    {
        base.Move();// <<==- replace
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct. The following code compiles just fine for me: `public class Piece { } internal class Pawn : Piece { public Pawn() { } }`.

Comment: Looks like you're right. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500593/what-does-a-public-constructor-on-an-internal-class-mean

Comment: Please don't vandalise your answer. If you want to you can simply delete your answer.

Comment: I just updated it with a contractor of : 

    public class Piece  //<T> // using ' T '  as the generic variable of all the below- 
    {
        public Piece()
        {

        }

and it seems to be working now. I do think I remember hearing that default/ implied/ initial constructors were initialized as internal though. idk. It seems to be working now. I'm just not sure if I should include the private fields within the constructor :/

Comment: actually apparently not. I just tried it and the whole file lit-up red.